# How to fix an admin link created from a shell script?

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I am creating a link to a specific action in the admin section which will be emailed.

The task is run in a `shell` script called `rules.php`.

So I generate the admin url with:

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("productmodule/adminhtml_trace/download", array('csv' => $filename));
```

When running the script from command line:

`php -f rules.php apply`

The generated url is:

https://mysite.dev/**rules.php**/productmodule/adminhtml_trace/download/csv/file_1/key/3f5f888f5b6f191ab32e496f7e2bafd8/

Where I want the url to be:

https://mysite.dev/**index.php**/productmodule/adminhtml_trace/download/csv/file_1/key/3f5f888f5b6f191ab32e496f7e2bafd8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on [Stackoverflow magento admin url from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765290/using-geturl-in-a-magento-shell-script)

You need to set the type:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array(
  'order_id' => 123,
  '_type' => Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB
));
```